# Jedis blocks forever getting connection to Amazon

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, redis, jedis

Hello I am debugging Jedis talking to an Amazon Elasticache Redis 2.6.13

I am having trouble with Jedis being unable to get a connection.  Currently, I am using all the default values, and I am seeing that it always blocks forever when I try to get a connection.  I.e. this call blocks

```
            Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
```

However, if I leave the Server alone for a while, it seems to work again.  This indicates that something is being used up by Jedis and eventually cleaned up by a lower level.

I believe I have some problem with my configuration, but it works fine with Redis on my laptop (2.6.10)

I found a blog from 2011 that talks about configuration, which had a very interesting sentence in the middle

```
http://biasedbit.com/redis-jedispool-configuration/

"The annoyance here is that in a JedisPool by default, connections will die of inactivity and no new ones will be spawned."
```

I have also seen questions indicating that Jedis sometimes creates a new connection each time, and does not reuse existing connections.  For examnple

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jedis_redis/H3FhLtwkDo8
```

Is anyone using Jedis with Amazon Elasticache?  How is it working for you?  What is your configuration?

Also, does anyone recognize the issues described above.  How does one avoid/fix them?

Thank you
Peter

Answer (score 3):

Here is an update:

JedisConfig has maxTotal and maxIdle tuning parameters

```
    JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig(); 
    // default 8 : Maximum active connections to Redis instance
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(maxTotal);  
    // default 8 : Maximum number of idle connections to Redis
    poolConfig.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
```

Jedis is apparently greedy and will create that many connections, even when it does not have to.

I was setting the max to 100 and running 3 servers.

Unfortunately, the Amazon Redis instance only seems to have about 128 available connections, so my servers were starving each other.

Using the Amazon Elasticache console I was able to see the number of connections ramp up until a server was rebooted